# require('jquery') vs require('semantic-ui-css'), only one works in react programming with webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack, semantic-ui

While programming in react and (and I use webpack), I noticed that

```
require('jquery')
```

works after a `npm install jquery --save` but

```
require('semantic-ui-css')
```

does not after a `npm install semantic-ui-css --save`.

How does webpack makes it possible that `jquery` can just be imported like that, but `semantic-ui-css` cannot.

In other words, how does webpack even resolve a given name to a module to load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at their respective `package.json` files - [the jQuery one](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/package.json) has the `main` property set to `dist/jquery.js`, whereas [the semantic-ui-css one](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-CSS/blob/master/package.json) does not have it at all. Whatever file is set there is what Node/Webpack will provide when you import the package. If it's not there, you can't import the package by name - you either have to specify a particular file (e.g. `semantic-ui-css/semantic.css`) or use [Webpack's module aliasing functionality](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias).